# How to redirect users to the desktop site if the files doesn't exist in the mobile site?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mobile, subdomain

I have created a `www.example.com` and `m.example.com`. The `m.example.com` resides inside the `htdocs/m/` folder. I am using the below codes in the `.htaccess`:

```
# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

#mobile
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ m/$1 [L]

# Resolve .php file for extension-less php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Now,if users hit `m.example.com/abc` and if the `abc` files doesn’t exist, it will redirect users to the error page, as I have the below code on the `.htaccess` code inside the `htdocs/m/` folder

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://m.example.com/error
```

But now I want the users to be redirected to `www.example.com/abc` instead, as `abc` may be a valid file in the desktop version. Only if the files also doesn't exist in the desktop site, the users will be redirected to the error page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place this rule as **first rule** in `DocumentRoot` of `m.example.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks. But now all links got redirected to www.example.com/page, even when the file exists...

Comment: That cannot redirect existing file because of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition. Are you sure `/page` is an **existing file**?

Comment: /page.php is an existing file.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, can you help more with this one?- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531318
Can't figure out how to configure properly... Thanks!