# mod_rewrite is preventing my form to be submitted as desired

Tags: forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, post, subdomain

I have created a www.example.com and m.example.com. The m.example.com resides inside the htdocs/m/ folder. I am also deleting the '.php' extensions using .htaccess. I am having the below codes on the root directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

#mobile
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ m/$1 [L]

# Resolve .php file for extension-less php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

I have forms in the m.example.com. For example in m.example.com/myform.php, I have

```
<form method="post" action="processform.php">
 .....
</form>
```

I want it to be submitted to the m/ folder (/m/processform.php), but now it always submit to the processform.php of the main directory. I have tried `action="//m.example.com/processform.php"` but no luck.

Anyone know kow to solve it? Thanks!

**Update:**
if the method of the form is get instead of post, the form will be submitted correctly (to /m/processform.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your rules are skipping `POST` requests from all rewrite rules. You can tweak the rules to skip `POST` from external redirects and keep internal rewrites active/enabled for `POST` like this:

```
# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

#mobile
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!m/).*)$ m/$1 [L,NC]

# Resolve .php file for extension-less php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

PS: I have also simplified your 2nd rule.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the first redirect is interferring with the POST request, try changing the request regex to:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
```